# Ruby validation of name, email, and phone number

Tags: ruby

After creating the loop to check that the phone number is 10 characters I believe the phone issue is now resolved. Now I'm working with checking the email address, name, and making sure it outputs correctly, and making sure 2 names are entered by the user. Having issues getting the email address to validate and output in the correct format.

```
    NAME_PATTERN = /([\w\-\']{2,})([\s]+)([\w\-\']{2,})/
    EMAIL_PATTERN = /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\Z/i
    PHONE_PATTERN = /^(?:\+?1\s*(?:[.-]\s*)?)?(?:\(\s*([2-9]1[02-9]|[2-9][02-8]1|[2-9][02-8][02-9])\s*\)|([2-9]1[02-9]|[2-9][02-8]1|[2-9][02-8][02-9]))\s*(?:[.-]\s*)?([2-9]1[02-9]|[2-9][02-9]1|[2-9][02-9]{2})\s*(?:[.-]\s*)?([0-9]{4})$/

    def valid_name?(name)
        !!name.match(NAME_PATTERN)
    end

    puts "Enter your first and last name (John Doe): "

    while (name=gets)

        names = name.split(" ", 2)
        if valid_name?(name)
            puts "Great, that looks like it could work."
            break
            else
            puts "Please enter first and last name."
        end
    end

    def valid_email?(email)
        !!email.match(EMAIL_PATTERN)
    end

    puts "Enter your email address (joe@info.com): "

    while (email = gets)

        if valid_email?(email)
            puts "Great, that looks like it could work."
            break
        else
            puts "Invalid email address entered. Please try again. "
        end
    end

    def valid_phone?(number)
        !!number.match(PHONE_PATTERN)
    end

    puts "Enter your phone number including area code (numbers only): "

    while (number=gets)

        if valid_phone?(number)
            puts "Great, that looks like it could work."
            break   
        else
            puts "Invalid phone number entered. Please try again."
            end
    end

    puts names
    puts email
    puts number
```

Comment: Are you using rails?

Comment: No just Ruby, using notepad++ and CMD with Ruby.

Comment: I'm not making assumptions, I'm requiring a certain format for the phone numbers (888) 555-1234, and checking that an email address is in a valid format like: name@me.com. The name section should be able to include any character, an @ symbol to separate the name and domain, and .com or a similar format.

Comment: @tadman I think your scorn is premature. It looks to me like OP is writing this program as an exercise in learning Ruby, not as a production application.

Comment: @Natela I understand where you're coming from, but `sergei@google` is theoretically a valid email address because [`.google` is a thing](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2014/11/26/google_turns_on_google_internet_extension/): Your presumption that there will be at least two components to the domain is not correct. There's nothing more infuriating to people than when they end up [falling victim to sloppy programming](http://www.wired.com/2015/11/null/) or how [people with apostrophes in their name are always having trouble](http://usatoday30.usatoday.com/news/nation/2008-02-21-2916826860_x.htm).

Comment: I am trying to teach myself ruby by trying to solve problems in a book I purchased. "Ruby Programming" by Jerry Lee Ford Jr. The problem specifies that the format must have a domain name with .com, .edu, or something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you didn't intend to use the assignment operator here:

```
if (email = /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\Z/i)
```

Try this:

```
if email =~ /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\Z/i
```

You have a similar error in the `phone_number` method:

```
if number = 10
```

I'm not sure what you intended here. Perhaps this?

```
if number.size == 10
```

You have more problems, however. Take a look at this loop:

```
loop do
  if number.size == 10
    break   
  else
    puts "Invalid phone number entered. Please try again."
  end
end
```

How will the user ever exit this loop if the number is invalid? The value of `number` never changes.

Comment: Thanks Jordan. How to I implement the phone number validation within the loop so it stops when a valid 10 digit number is entered.]

Comment: Separate your input/output logic from your validation logic. Don't print error messages in your validation methods. Have the logic that accepts user input call `phone_number` in a loop and check its return value (it could perhaps return `nil` if the value is invalid).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a Ruby flavoured approach to what you're trying to do:

```
# Define constants for things that are special and get re-used.
EMAIL_PATTERN = /\A\S+@\S+\z/

# Methods that test something and return true or false often end with
# a question mark (?) to indicate this.
def valid_email?(email)
  !!email.match(EMAIL_PATTERN)
end

# Try and keep your support methods separate from the main body of
# your program.

puts "Enter your email address (joe@info.com): "

# This sets up a loop that waits until you get a valid response.
while (email = gets)
  email = gets

  if valid_email?(email)
    puts "Great, that looks like it could work"
    break
  else
    # Note that the message is rendered here, not in the validation
    # method, so there's no assumptions about how this method is used.
    puts "Invalid email address entered. Please try again. "
  end
end
```

If you try and structure your code this way you'll find it's a lot easier to keep things organized. This is one of the big challenges when learning programming so as not to get overwhelmed.

Regular expressions are great for validating things that conform to a very specific pattern, but try not to get overly confident in the pattern of everyday things. Even the humble IPv4 address comes in a multitude of forms.